# Comment reply select not working good

Tags: php, select

I have a problem and I don't know how to resolve...
I have page with comments and page with replies.
Down is my code, everything is ok, it shows all I want but the problem is, when I click on the comment to go to the page with a reply, the id it gets is wrong.

Example: for the first comment I need to have id=1, second id=2 etc. But I get id=1 for all the comments where user_id = 1 and not id from comment.
Sorry, my English.

```
<?php
    $id = $show['id'];
    $sq = "SELECT * FROM comments, users WHERE comments.user_id = users.id";   
    $re = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sq);                                         
    while($abc=mysqli_fetch_assoc($re)){
?> 
    <div class="card hoverable q_area">
        <div class="card-content">
            <div class="chip">
                <img src="<?php echo $show['profile_foto'] ?>">                     
        <?php   echo  $abc['user'] . " said:"; ?> 
            </div><br /> 
            <div id="comm">
        <?php   $a=substr(str_replace(' ','-',$abc['question']), 0, 50);  ?>   
                <h5><a href="replys.php?id=<?php echo $abc['id'] ?>&reply=<?php echo $a ?>">
        <?php   echo $abc['comment']; ?></a></h5> <br />
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
        <?php   }   ?>
```

---

If I change that select like this:

```
$sq = "SELECT * FROM comments";
```

then link id work, but I can't echo the user who said the comment.

```
database tables:
users - id, user, pass
comments- id, user_id, comment
```

please help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Your `query - $sq` to this one:

`$sq = "SELECT a.*, b.user FROM comments as a, users as b WHERE a.user_id = b.id"`

Comment: i just did it 5 mins ago. But this is the answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You just nedd a alias in your select;

```
$sq = "SELECT *, comments.id as comment_id FROM comments, users WHERE comments.user_id = users.id";
```

And your link will be some like this:

```
<h5><a href="replys.php?id=<?php echo $abc['comment_id'] ?>&reply=<?php echo $a ?>">
```

I hope I've helped.